# How to run the docker image with <none> tag

Tags: docker, docker-run

I have a docker image with `<none>` tag.[image]

I want to run the hello-world image with TAG `<none>`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to run a dangling image, you first need to tag that image. You can do this by using image ID.

For example:

```sh
docker tag [IMAGE_ID] [REPOSITORY]:[TAG]
```

Now you can run that image with the tag you just defined.

Answer (score 7):

You can run a container from a specific image by using the image's ID, like:

```sh
docker run -it efb6339f1b3e /bin/bash
```

If you want to give your image a tag, you can do that by using `-t` option in the `docker build` command, like:

```sh
docker build -t codinghaus/hello-world:1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
docker tag <image-name> <image-name>[:tag]
```

Example:

```sh
docker tag hello_world hello_world[:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran it like this successfully and the tag of the image is 'none'
[image]

Command on Macos:
docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash --env-file ~/docker/env.list -u root a480ebfb5d6d9ef62eef279512f6cadb57717efaa8b05afe301c52ed27ff9ef0